# i want display latest 4 records in angular2

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array

I want to display latest 4 records but it shows all d records.

```
public moderlist=[];
public notification1=[];
public createdon1=[];
public notificationlabel:any=[];
public createdonlabel:any=[];

getAllNotifications() {
    debugger;
    this.RedBenchService.getNotifications().subscribe(results => {
        // this.moderlist
        debugger;
        this.moderlist= results;
        for(let i=0; i<this.moderlist.length;i++) {
            this.notification1.push(this.moderlist[i].Notification1);
            this.createdon1.push(this.moderlist[i].CreatedOn);
        }
        this.notificationlabel=this.notification1;   
        this.createdonlabel=this.createdon1;                     
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I want display latest 4 records in angular2

Comment: Does `let i=this.moderlist.length-4` work ?

Comment: no its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public moderlist=[];
public notification1=[];
public createdon1=[];
public notificationlabel:any=[];
public createdonlabel:any=[];
public fourNotification:any=[];
    getAllNotifications() {
         debugger;
    this.RedBenchService.getNotifications().subscribe(
      results => {
        // this.moderlist
          debugger;
        this.moderlist= results;
        for(let i=0; i<=4;i++)
                {

                   debugger;
                  this.fourNotification.push(this.moderlist[i]);
                  }

              },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the logic in the for loop as follows.

```
if(this.moderlist.length >= 4){
     for(let i=this.moderlist.length-1; i>=this.moderlist.length-4;i--) {
            this.notification1.push(this.moderlist[i].Notification1);
            this.createdon1.push(this.moderlist[i].CreatedOn);
        }
     }
```